# Nuget ignores credentials for network share

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am using network windows share as nuget packages source. And everything works fine except our admin wants to set some authentification on this share.

**Problem**: configure nuget to use share with user/pass.

**What I've tried**: changing my nuget.config, adding packageSourceCredentials for this share. Here is my changed nuget.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="true" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Custom" value="\\some\share\nuget\" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <Custom>
      <add key="Username" value="test" />
      <add key="Password" value="somelongencodedvalue" />
    </Custom>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

But nuget tries to login using currently logged in windows user and is not using credentials from config. What am I doing wrong? Does packageSourceCredentials work only with http package sources?

Answer (score 0):

You make nothing wrong.
I got today same problem. I found out that nuget first tries to authenficate with the current credentials of the user. In case this failed, the credentials of the config file are will be taken.